# Computation for tensor product over $R \otimes R^{op}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a $k$-algebra (R commutative) and $M$, $T$ be $R$-bimodules. $R^e := R \otimes_k R^{op}$

I am stuck on this computation: $T^e \otimes_{R^e}M = T \otimes_RM\otimes_RT$.

---

By using associativity, $(T \otimes_{k}T^{op}) \otimes_{R^e}M = T \otimes_{k}(T^{op} \otimes_{R^e}M)$. Also, $T^{op}$ (resp. $M$) is a right (resp. left) ${R^e}$-module, hence both $R$-bimodules. Is it true that $T^{op} \otimes_{R^e}M \cong M \otimes_{R^e}T$?

Comment: The answer is yes: in this case by trivial reasons, since $R$ is commutative then $R \cong R^{op}$, so that everywhere you write $op$, you can delete it. I'm not really sure about the non-commutative case, but a similar identity should hold, as it is useful for calculating Hochschild homology. I'm going to check and let you know.

Comment: @juandiegorojas Ok so we have $(T \otimes_{k}T^{op}) \otimes_{R^e}M = T \otimes_{k}(T^{op} \otimes_{R^e}M) = T \otimes_{k}(M \otimes_{R^e}T)$. How do we make it precise that $T \otimes_{k}(M \otimes_{R^e}T) \cong T \otimes_{R}M \otimes_{R}T$? Is it because $R$ is a $k$-algebra and both $T$ and $M$ are $R$-bimodules?

Comment: I'm used to the the notation $T^{op}$ and $T^e$ when $T$ is an algebra. Could you explain exactly what you mean by them when $T$ is a bimodule? In particular, what right $R^e$-module structure on $T\otimes_k T^{op}$ are you using when you write $(T\otimes_k T^{op})\otimes_{R^e}M$? To use associativity as you do, you seem to be regarding $T^{op}$ as a right $R^{op}$-module and not using any action on the other $T$, but in $T\otimes_RM\otimes_RT$ you are using one $R$-action on each copy of $T$, so something seems wrong.

Comment: @JeremyRickard We have a ring map $R \to T$ and $T^e$ is an $R^e$ module. Also $T^e = T \otimes T^{op}$. I guess $T$ is just an $R$-module, so I think the base ring in the tensor product $T^e = T \otimes_R T^{op}$ is $R$ instead of $k$ as I first thought. Also, I thought I could use associativity but maybe not; I am a little confused when tensoring wrt $R^e$.